# How to remove sprites shadow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to load this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dK20.png) without its shadow

I've tried getting the color key by printing the color where my mouse is and and then setting the images color key to that color. I also tried adding `convert_alpha()` when loading the image but it still didn't work. Am I just getting the color wrong or is there another way of removing colors other than setting the color key. I tried searching google but it only shows setting the color key.

My current code

```
import pygame, sys


pygame.init()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:

                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                print(display.get_at(pygame.mouse.get_pos()))

    display.fill('white')

    image = pygame.image.load('mystic_woods_free_v0.2/sprites/characters/player.png')
    image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (image.get_rect().width * 6, image.get_rect().height * 6))
    image.set_colorkey((138, 141, 151))

    display.blit(image, (0, 0))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score -1):

I found out the true color of the shadow by using
`pygame.image.load(...).convert()`
and then using that color as the colorkey (which works without .covert() )